# Can I see/change text encoding in Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word, encoding, unicode, non-ascii

I received a Word document with Bulgarian text. When I copy-paste it to our web based CMS  some letters change (possibly to Russian??).

If I `copy` and `paste special` (from Word 2003 to Word 2003 as `unformatted Unicode`), some letters change as well!

So I think that the document I received is not in Unicode but uses some Bulgarian code page. I already set the `language` to `Bulgarian` in both documents but that didn't help.

- Can I confirm that the original doc is not in unicode (and if so, how)?
- Can I convert it to Unicode (and is so, how)?
- Is that likely to solve the problem or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: What happens if you copy and paste the code into WordPad? And NotePad? Does the same error persist?

Comment: http://www.coolutils.com/Word-to-Unicode

Comment: @DaveRook: yes, in Notepad we see the exact same problem. Even changing the font to `Arial Unicode MS` within Word 2003 triggers the problem. I'll see if I can try the tool. Already contacted my Bulgarian ex colleague as well.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so now I know...

The letters don't really change: they have different visual representations but they are still the same letters. This is known as **manuscript style** versus **print style**. The text looks different but hasn't actually changed.